# I don't know what key is ATTN key

Tags: key

I don't know what key it is. Please could you give me a description or an image for know it?
I've looked for it but I didn't find anything.
Thanks

Comment: Some Googling around suggests it may be the ESCAPE key or the Pause/Break key or the combination Ctrl-Alt-Del... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Alt-Delete  http://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/IBM_Keyboard

Comment: No,it isn't Esc key or Pause/Break key Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Shift + Esc worked for me in a QMF emulator